# Collapsing the header image with scrolling the recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a XML Layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="realup.ir.teacher.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/header">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_head">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/realup"
                android:id="@+id/header_image"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/recycle"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, I have a recyclerview and I want to when the recyclerview is scrolling down, the Image view be collapsed along with scrolling the recyclerview. Can you help me? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your RecyclerView should be in the Coordinatorlayout to perform the animation and use a NestedScrollView as parent for your RecyclerView :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="realup.ir.teacher.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/header">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_head">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/realup"
                android:id="@+id/header_image"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recycle"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

To get a smooth scroll effet add in your code :

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycle);
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Thanks you, developer ;)

Comment: You are welcome :) You can remove the relative layout if you have no need

Answer (score 0):

Take `CoordinatorLayout` as a parent layout and put RecyclerView in FrameLayout;

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:background="#e7e5e5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/realup"
            android:id="@+id/header_image"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/task_list"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="85dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you mean, I should delete the Relative Layout as a parent for whole the screen?

Comment: Comment your whole xml and put this and check what happen

Comment: put your own recyclerview id in xml